# Confusion in initialising GraphQL Dataloader in context

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, dataloader, apollo-federation

`context: ({ req }) => { if (req) { return { ip: headers.userip, headers, userLanguage, decodedToken, dataLoaders: { seoDataLoader: createSeoDataLoader() } } } }`
Here I create a createSeoDataLoader instace for every request . now suppose if i have 50 loaders     then for every request 50 loaders instance created and i think its not good. please anyone give me some clairification about this thing. thanks

at every request create a instance of all 50 dataloader is it good or not ?. i need to figureout this thing please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single answer to your question that fits all scenarios, but yes, if you're following the DataSource model, you create all dataSources at the start of the request. This should do *VERY MINIMAL* work.

Internally, you want all of that functionality to be "lazy loaded", so it doesn't actually do things 50 times if the client is only asking to do one thing. Setting the dataSources like this allow you to initialize them with components of your request, too. For example:

- if you have a dataSource that is going to be making a request to an external source, it may need the accessToken to pass through;
- if your dataSources are making authorization decisions, you may create an "authorizer" that you pass into them;
- if your dataSources need IP addresses or other context initialize your dataSources with them. Then you can write resolvers that don't know they're in Express;

```
  context: ({ req }) => {
    if (req) {
      const headers = req.headers;
      const userLanguage = ....
      const accessToken = req.headers.authorization;
      const user = verifyToken(accessToken);
      const authorizer = createAuthorizer({ user });
      const dataSources = {
        seoDataLoader: createSeoDataLoader({ accessToken, authorizer, tracking: { ipAddress: headers.userip })
        someProxyDataLoader: createSomething({ accessToken }),
      }
      return {
        dataLoaders,
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice because you can't predict which loader will be used in incoming query so you need to repeatly prepare them all for each single query.

The cost may be not that high, but this feels not orginazed, it feels bad for puting all loader instances in a single context.

For python, based on pydantic, I wrote a very simple schema based query pattern.

```py
    import asyncio
    from typing import List
    from pydantic import BaseModel
    from pydantic_resolve import Resolver, LoaderDepend as LD
    
    async def batch_person_age_loader(names: List[str]):
        print(names)
        _map = {
            'kikodo': 21,
            'John': 14,
            '老王': 40,
        }
        return [_map.get(n) for n in names]
    
    class Person(BaseModel):
        name: str
    
        age: int = 0
        def resolve_age(self, loader=LD(batch_person_age_loader)):
            return loader.load(self.name)
    
        is_adult: bool = False
        def post_is_adult(self):
            return self.age > 18
    
    async def simple():
        people = [Person(name=n) for n in ['kikodo', 'John', '老王']]
        people = await Resolver().resolve(people)
        print(people)
        # query query kikodo,John,老王 (N+1 query fixed)
        # [Person(name='kikodo', age=21, is_adult=True), Person(name='John', age=14, is_adult=False), Person(name='老王', age=40, is_adult=True)]
    
    asyncio.run(simple())
```

So that I can declare loaders inside resolve funcitons.

It's not so friendly for frontend, it losts the all-in-one query plaground, splitting it back to each single request.

But it's super friendly to backend.

If you expose your openapi, and turns it into client sdk, it's also super friendly to frontend.

https://github.com/allmonday/pydantic-resolve